# Shortcode output based on "if" array value is provided

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am new to building shortcodes in WordPress, so I'm sure this is an easy answer that probably has to do with my syntax. What I want to do is insert dynamic tracking numbers based on whatever the admin wants to track.

```
[phone tracking="WHATEVER"]WHATEVER PHONE NUMBER[/phone]
```

In my first iteration, I will be doing this:

```
[phone tracking="general"]561-444-4440[/phone]
```

Here's the custom shortcode in my functions.php file, which is sort-of working - it's outputting the 4255209 number right now.

```
        // Dynamic tracking number shortcode
function dynamic_tracking_phone_number( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Map the dynamic numbers as attributes here [phone tracking="general"]561-444-4440[/phone]
    $args = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'tracking' => '',
        ), $atts);
        $general = '4255209';
        $homepage = '6015036';

        if ( empty ( $args['tracking'])) {
            return 'Please specify tracking attribute'; }

        if ($args['tracking'] = 'general') { 
            $out = '<a href="tel:+1561' . $general . '" target="_blank" /> '. $content .'</a>';}

        elseif ($args['tracking'] = 'homepage') {
            $out = '<a href="tel:+1561' . $homepage . '" target="_blank" /> '. $content .'</a>';}

        return html_entity_decode($out);
    } add_shortcode( 'phone', 'dynamic_tracking_phone_number' );
```

Output on the front-end:

```
<a href="tel:+15614255209" target="_blank">561-444-4440</a>
```

But when I test for the attribute in the shortcode as tracking="homepage", it still outputs 4255209. Also, I am sure I am being redundant in my $out code. Any help and guidance in the form of examples would be great, thanks!

Comment: Where is `$args` defined? I don't see it as a parameter there

Comment: Thank you -- fixed that, and update post...still not outputting the dynamic numbers though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `==` to check whether two things are equal. The single `=` is not for comparison, it's only for assignment. Like `x = 5`, that's assigning the value 5 to the variable `x`. When you say `if ($args['tracking'] = 'general')`, you're assigning the value `'general'` to `$args['tracking']`.

So the main part of the fix for you is to correct these two lines:

`if ($args['tracking'] = 'general')`

and

`elseif ($args['tracking'] = 'homepage')`

That is, change the `=` to `==`.

I'm a little unclear on how you're using that `$args` variable. It seems to me that if you want to access `'tracking'`, then you need to do

`$args[0]['tracking']`

as opposed to

`$args['tracking']`

But like I say, I'm unclear. That language looks like PHP to me, but maybe it's not. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It works now. I knew it was something stupid that I just didn't know. On the second recommendation, adding the [0] in the $args variable...it's working without that, but I am curious. Would you mind explaining that?

Comment: Because of the way you've defined `$args` -- `$args = shortcode_atts( array( 'tracking' => '',), $atts);` You have an `array` inside another object, the `shortcode_atts` object. This might be something Wordpress is doing to alter the way PHP works? I don't know, I've never touched Wordpress.

Comment: @tommycopeland Ok, I get it now. `shortcode_atts` is a Wordpress function, not an object; I thought it was an object you had defined yourself. So yeah, the way you're doing it makes sense to me now.

Comment: Correct! Your answer on the "=" versus "==" cleared it all up, that's all I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the difference between the "=" and the "==" that @GreatBigBore had provided, which compares the user-provided attribute variable with the IF statement. Thank you!